# how to use post in "Request" function at firefox-addon-sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, request, add-on, firefox-addon-sdk

I read about function 'Request' as this link: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html

And I would like to use the "post" method.  There is no explaination or example on how to send a variable from JS to my server with the post method. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just change the get() call in the example on that page with post().

```
exports.main = function() {
    var Request = require("request").Request;
    Request({
      url: "http://google.com/",
      content: {q: "test"},
      onComplete: function (response) {
        console.log(response.text);
      }
    }).post();
};
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but you answered only about my first question. 
my second one is about how can i send values from javascript to the post method. 
if you do not understand i will trying to explain better
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Roy: the 'content: {q: "test"},' line does that. If you don't see the effect on the server side, you should really provide details about your server side.