# Firefox ADD-ON SDK: can I use page-worker with POST method?

Tags: firefox, post, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to use the POST method with page-worker ?

I could not find anything about setting the request method in the docs, and searching the web was also without relevant results.
The only thing I found is [how to use POST in the request function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868175/how-to-use-post-in-request-function-at-firefox-addon-sdk), but that gives me the resulting web page as text string instead of a workable DOM.

Well, if POST will absolutely not work with page-worker, parsing this text will be a plan B. But a very ugly one, so I really would appreciate not needing to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to make a post form a content script that you attached to a page?  Usually this is not possible to prevent [Cross-Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.  What I've done is to relay what needs to be posted from the content script to the add-on script ([see the docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html)) and having the add-on script do the POST [request](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html).

Comment: It is already done in the add-on script. The purpose is to add additional info to a page. That additional info can only be fetched with a POST request. After doing that, the add-on script passes the fetched info to the content script.